# DbContext-FromSql can't replace the database-name

Tags: sql, asp.net-core, .net-core, dbcontext, entity-framework-core

I'm using my .NET Core application to query some data. In my application I am using two different contexts. As LINQ/EF are not able to join between two contexts, I am doing my query with DbContext..FromSql:

```
IQueryable<Articles> query = _contextA.Articles.FromSql<Articles>(
    @"SELECT    a.*, ra.Barcode AS RequestedBarcode
    FROM        dbo.Articles a
    INNER JOIN  Webservice.dbo.RequestArticle ra
            ON  ra.ProducerId = a.ProducerId AND ra.Barcode = a.Barcode
    WHERE       ra.RequestId = {0}",
    ArticleRequestGuid);
```

This query works like a charm. Now I want to replace my "Webservice"-database-name dynamically from my other context.

```
IQueryable<Articles> query = _contextA.Articles.FromSql<Articles>(
    @"SELECT    a.*, ra.Barcode AS RequestedBarcode
    FROM        dbo.Articles a
    INNER JOIN  {1}.dbo.RequestArticle ra
            ON  ra.ProducerId = a.ProducerId AND ra.Barcode = a.Barcode
    WHERE       ra.RequestId = {0}",
    ArticleRequestGuid,
    _contextB.Database.GetDbConnection().Database);
```

The value in **_contextB.Database.GetDbConnection().Database** is the exact correct value-string. But the query still fails with following error message:

```
"message": "Falsche Syntax in der Nähe von '.'.",
"detail": "
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.<>c.<ExecuteDbDataReaderAsync>b__107_0(Task`1 result)\r\n
at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationResultTaskFromResultTask`2.InnerInvoke()\r\n
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()\r\n
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n
```

"Falsche Syntax in der Nähe von '.'." means "Wrong syntax close to '.'."

What is done wrong?

---

Update:
The example before was done with Core 1.1. Now I've updated to Core 2.0.

This works fine:

```
IQueryable<Articles> query = _contextA.Articles.FromSql<Articles>(
@"SELECT    a.*, ra.Barcode AS RequestedBarcode
FROM        dbo.Articles a
INNER JOIN  Webservice.dbo.RequestArticle ra
        ON  ra.ProducerId = a.ProducerId AND ra.Barcode = a.Barcode
WHERE       ra.RequestId = {ArticleRequestGuid}");
```

This is not working:

```
string webserviceDatabaseName = "Webservice";
IQueryable<Articles> query = _contextA.Articles.FromSql<Articles>(
@"SELECT    a.*, ra.Barcode AS RequestedBarcode
FROM        dbo.Articles a
INNER JOIN  {webserviceDatabaseName}.dbo.RequestArticle ra
        ON  ra.ProducerId = a.ProducerId AND ra.Barcode = a.Barcode
WHERE       ra.RequestId = {ArticleRequestGuid}");
```

Seems like this won't work.

Comment: I would try two things. First define a helpvariable and catch "_contextB.Database.GetDbConnection().Database" in it; and then use this helpvariable in the .FromSql<>() statement. If this doesn't work I would also try to change the current order of {1} and {0} into the sequential order {0} and {1}.

Comment: I am using a help-variable for the database name and also the sequential  order of {0} and {1} is the other way around. I just copied the first code block and changed it to the second code block by hand to highlight the changes and shorten the question.

Comment: Which version of EF Core do you use?

Comment: 1.0. and planning to go 2.0 next week.

Comment: Take a look at the fragment (concerning EF Core 2.0) in this video ( https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q2mMbjw6cLA&index=4&list=LLYMpABfqmzOd9dFNKrXAdrg ) around 1:17:30. They wouldn't demonstrate this if it would not also work with two parameters in stead of one. Maybe you should retry this in EF Core 2.0.

Comment: I've updated my question. Doesn't work with Core 2.0 as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the question is open a while, I used alternatively "String.Format" instead of the Variable-names directly within the SQL statement:

```
string sqlQuery = String.Format(
    @"SELECT    a.*, ra.Barcode AS RequestedBarcode
      FROM        dbo.Articles a
      INNER JOIN  {0}.dbo.RequestArticle ra
        ON  ra.ProducerId = a.ProducerId AND ra.Barcode = a.Barcode
      WHERE       ra.RequestId = '{1}'",
    _contextB.Database.GetDbConnection().Database,
    ArticleRequestGuid
    );
var query = _contextA.Articles.FromSql<Articles>(sqlQuery);
```

Somehow the first variant wasn't working at all. Seems like it's not worth it putting more effort into that problem.